# Bitsqaure: Can I contact arbitrator before time limit?

Tags: transactions, buy-bitcoins

So I started my first transaction on BitSquare. I waited for about a day for block confirmations. Finally got the message saying that I could go through with payment to the bitcoin seller using payment method: ClearXchange.

However, when I went to clearxchange and input the seller's info, the service says that he is not eligible to receive money with clearxchange. I would like to be able to contact the arbitrator to let him know of the situation, but according to the system, I have to wait for the maximum allowed transaction time (or half of it) to pass and then I and the seller will get the change to open a dispute.

I am concerned that if the seller gets to open dispute first for not receiving payment and contact the arbitrator, that I will loose my deposit even though he is the one not properly setup to receive payment. I would like to do 'cmd+o' but bitsquare says that I should only do that if there is a software bug!

Do I have no choice but to wait? Are there any other options open to me for contacting the arbitrator ASAP? Could I do 'cmd+o' and state a "lack of ability to comunicate" as a software bug? What's the appropriate course of action here?

Thank you